# Can't compile every .pug file in a folder using webpack

Tags: webpack, pug-loader

I'm trying to create a environment using Webpack with a techstack based on:

- pug, for template HTML
- sass, for CSS
- ES7

But I'm having issues creating pug HTML files.

Here's a gist with my webpack.config.js file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/84c02222a44ce219c35ff1a8beeff720

What exactly I'm trying to achieve:

I have a folder structure based on

> - app
>
>   > ./pug
>   >
>   > > ./components, ./views

And what I want to do is compile every pug file on views' folder and turn it into a HTML and send it to dist folder.

You guys can help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. I don't remember exactly where I found this solution, but it worked haha

Here's how we can compile every `.pug` inside a folder:

First, add this to your `module` object, in webpack file:

`{ test: /\.pug$/, loaders: [ 'file-loader?name=[path][name].html', 'pug-html-loader?pretty&exports=false' ] },`

And then add this function to webpack's entry file
`function requireAll(r) { r.keys().filter(r => r.forEach(r)) }
requireAll(require.context('./', true, /\.pug$/));`